# Mathematical Statistics course

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, hypothesis-testing

Which book can be the course book in this direction?
I am teaching a course to the basic level on college students.
I have did my efforts towards handouts but there may be a book having small short concepts. Please guide me in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

Probability and Statistics for Engineering ,  Jay Devore . can be an option.

Comment: Reviewed Devore/Berk book in preparation. Think highly of it. // Older, cheaper, more technical, avail in paperback: Bain/Englehardt